# Can the requireJS optimizer update static file references and names with MD5 checksums?

Tags: javascript, caching, requirejs, md5, r.js

I'm doing my first steps with the [`requirejs`](http://requirejs.org/) [`r.js` optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html).

I want fingerprint my static files by adding an `MD5 checksum` to filenames (as per [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching#LeverageBrowserCaching)) besides adding `Cache-Control` and `Expiry Headers`.

I'm wondering if there is any feature in the optimizer, that would create an MD5 checksum based on file contents and modify the filename, plus all references in the application accordingly.

Since there is a lot of dependency tracing and file manipulation when running the optimizer, I was wondering, if this was possible by default or if there is some plugin available to do this (although there is nothing on the [plugins](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Plugins) page)?

Thanks for infos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible as of now. More information on [Github](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/issues/55)/[Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/requirejs/wOSAa25d6xY)